# i cann't install eclipse ADT-plugin on ubuntu12.04

Tags: eclipse

i want to install the Eclipse Plugin but it doesn't work. and this is the detail.

```
Warning: You are installing software that contains unsigned content. The authenticity or validity of this software cannot be established. Do you want to continue with the installation?
  /home/adm/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0_1473617060/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_20.0.3.v201208082019-427395.jar
  /home/adm/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0_1473617060/features/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_20.0.3.v201208082019-427395
  /home/adm/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0_1473617060/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.base_20.0.3.v201208082019-427395.jar
  /home/adm/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0_1473617060/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms_20.0.3.v201208082019-427395.jar
  /home/adm/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0_1473617060/features/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms_20.0.3.v201208082019-427395
  /home/adm/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0_1473617060/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger_20.0.3.v201208082019-427395.jar
  /home/adm/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0_1473617060/features/com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger_20.0.3.v201208082019-427395
  /home/geekerstyle/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0_1473617060/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer_20.0.3.v201208082019-427395.jar
  /home/adm/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0_1473617060/features/com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer_20.0.3.v201208082019-427395
  /home/adm/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0_1473617060/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk_20.0.3.v201208082019-427395.jar
  /home/adm/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0_1473617060/features/com.android.ide.eclipse.ndk_20.0.3.v201208082019-427395
  /home/adm/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0_1473617060/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview_20.0.3.v201208082019-427395.jar
  /home/adm/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0_1473617060/features/com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview_20.0.3.v201208082019-427395
  /home/adm/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0_1473617060/plugins/overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay_20.0.3.v201208082019-427395.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26373), that error is expected. They do not sign the Android plugin.